# Хранимые процедуры SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица с 4 столбцами (genres, title, mov_year, rating).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же  есть хранимая процедура, которой на вход мы передаем несколько значений жанров(Например (Drama|Romance)) и процедура должна вернуть  ровно numbers фильмов для каждого переданного  жанра
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
для numbers=2 должны  получить что то типо такого, то есть фильмы выбираются по максимальному  рейтингу

```
genre, Title , mov_year, rating
Drama,xxx,yyyy,rr 
Drama,xxx,yyyy,rr
Romance,xxx,yyyy,rr
Romance,xxx,yyyy,rr
```

```
CREATE TABLE `selected_movies`(
            genres TEXT,
            title TEXT,
            movie_year INT,
            rating DOUBLE
        ) ;

INSERT INTO `selected_movies` (`genres`,`title`,`mov_year`,`rating`) VALUES ('Crime|Drama','Brother (Brat) (1997)','1997',5);
INSERT INTO `selected_movies` (`genres`,`title`,`mov_year`,`rating`) VALUES ('Animation|Children','Winnie Pooh (1969)','1969',3);
INSERT INTO `selected_movies` (`genres`,`title`,`mov_year`,`rating`) VALUES ('Drama|Romance','Sandpiper, The (1965)','1965',2);
INSERT INTO `selected_movies` (`genres`,`title`,`mov_year`,`rating`) VALUES ('Drama|Romance','Cruel Romance, A (Zhestokij Romans) (1984)','1984',5);
INSERT INTO `selected_movies` (`genres`,`title`,`mov_year`,`rating`) VALUES ('Comedy|Drama|Romance','Down Argentine Way (1940)','1940',3);
INSERT INTO `selected_movies` (`genres`,`title`,`mov_year`,`rating`) VALUES ('Comedy','Siam Sunset (1999)','1999',3);
INSERT INTO `selected_movies` (`genres`,`title`,`mov_year`,`rating`) VALUES ('Comedy|Romance','Spellbound (2011)','2011',2);
INSERT INTO `selected_movies` (`genres`,`title`,`mov_year`,`rating`) VALUES ('Documentary|Drama','On the Ropes (1999)','1999',4);
INSERT INTO `selected_movies` (`genres`,`title`,`mov_year`,`rating`) VALUES ('Comedy|Documentary','Animals are Beautiful People (1974)','1974',5);
INSERT INTO `selected_movies` (`genres`,`title`,`mov_year`,`rating`) VALUES ('Comedy','Calcium Kid, The (2004)','2004',4);
```

для этой таблице результат должен быть такой:

```
genre, Title , mov_year, rating
Drama,Brother (Brat) (1997), 1997, 5
Drama, "Cruel Romance, A (Zhestokij Romans) (1984)", 1984, 5
Romance, "Cruel Romance, A (Zhestokij Romans) (1984)", 1984, 5
Romance, Down Argentine Way (1940), 1940,3
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: Замените картинку на CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Покажите требуемый результат строго для показанных исходных данных. *процедура должна вернуть ровно numbers фильмов для каждого переданного жанра* По какому принципу отбирать три из всех возможных?

Comment: PS. Данные денормализованы. Крайне желательно нормализовать структуру.

Comment: мне просто не понятно как можно перебрать средствами sql входной параметр genres и вернуть таблицу в которой мы выберем фильмы для каждого жанра, вопрос изменил и добавил код создания таблицы

Comment: у вас должно быть 3 таблицы: фильмы, жанры и фильмы_жанры

Comment: Неужели нет способа сделать это через циклы в хранимых процедурах sql

Comment: А зачем, если можно проще и без хранимых процедур? Перечисление жаров в записях фильмов через разделитель приведёт к полному сканированию всех фильмов при выборке. Выборка, при увеличении числа фильмов, будет выполняться чудовищно долго. Оно вам надо?

Comment: *для этой таблице результат должен быть такой* Почему именно эти записи? для каждого жанра более 2 фильмов, но выбраны именно эти...

Comment: это при numbers = 2, фильмы выбираются по маскимальному рейтингу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *
          FROM JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@criteria, '|', '","'), '"]'),
                          '$[*]' COLUMNS (criteria VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsontable ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cte1.criteria 
                                       ORDER BY selected_movies.rating DESC, RAND()) rn 
          FROM cte1
          JOIN selected_movies ON LOCATE(cte1.criteria, selected_movies.genres) )
SELECT criteria, title, movie_year, rating
FROM cte2
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c8e790d08fb056b0775fc67460d7d88)

В принципе, всё можно упаковать в один CTE... только надо ли? ускорить не ускорит, а понятности может стать немного меньше.

Comment: это просто гениально, большое спасибо